# How to detect if you're in Zoom Call using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, webassembly

I wanted to create a chrome extension that can detect when I'm in a Zoom call. This is because my friends and I can know when we're busy (in zoom) / free (not in zoom).

I know with a desktop app, you can use execvp to detect which programs your computer is running and if it finds that "Zoom Meeting" is the title of one, it can return true.

However, we can't use execvp in javascript. So is detecting Zoom Call status even possible to do in Chrome extension? Maybe using Web Assembly?

Comment: Use a [Native Application](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thank you! Will look into it!!! :)